# How is Moodle Guest access different from publicly visible and why require a login?

Tags: moodle

Why does Moodle have a Guest user account? Is this not the same as simply making some areas of the site publicly visible?

I ask because when my session times out, it says "You are logged in as Guest" and there is a Log Out button... which would do what? If Guest is the default, why would you need to log in or out of it?

Why did they not simply have a Public level of access, which you can set items in your site to? There is a way to make things publicly visible, so I do not see the point of such a "user".

Comment: Imagine for a moment that it does make sense, and many people have the Guest password. You want to lock one of them out... Now you have to give the new Guest password to all those other people. Either someone is a user, or they are the Public. This is how the web works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Moodle you can enable/disable guest access at the site level and you can enable/disable guest access at the course level.

The 'guest' user has the 'guest' role that can be edited just like any other role in Moodle - so you can specify in a fine-grained way exactly what the guest user is and isn't allowed to access (so, by overriding the guest role, you might allow access to view some activities in a course but not others).

In theory, this could possibly all be managed with just a role and not a 'guest' user account. In reality there are so many places in the Moodle code that make use of the logged-in user object ($USER), that it is far simpler to point this at a 'guest' user (with all the right capabilities assigned), rather than having to check in every instance whether they are using guest access or real access.

So yes, 'guest' login is just public access to the site/course - but with the added ability to control the public access in a similar way to how the access of any 'normal' logged-in users is controlled.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose it is more complex than I could realize without understanding in detail. But it seems funny that you can "log out" of the Guest user. To what? If there is any functionality when not even logged in as Guest, then I think that Guest is somehow redundant. Since there is a way to hide the Guest login, then all the needed capabilities must be available without a Guest user.

Comment: You can hide the guest login in the site settings. Users will then only be able to access the courses with a real login.

Comment: But Guest would have to have a password, right? How does this work with the problem I mentioned in my Comment to my question? If there is no password for Guest, then it is Public. A web site either has credentials or it does not. There is no "sort-of" logged in. I think Guest is just silly.

Comment: It is not sort-of logged in. It is a way of controlling the access of not logged in users. Without the guest account you would not have fine control over what not logged in users can access. Also most of the code would have to be majorly rewritten to cope with working both with a user being logged in and public access. This way it can just work with the current user and not care if it is a real account or a guest account.

Comment: OK. But why is there a Log Out button when you are Guest, and why did it used to stop me from logging in as myself until I did hit the Log Out button, from Guest, which it forced me in to when my session timed out? It is like those cars whose doors lock automatically - I never asked for that!

Comment: In other words, Guest should be invisibly hidden and handled by the program itself, not me.

Comment: Yes, Guest is a weird user/account. But Moodle can be set up to auto login public users as Guest, so even if they don't realise they are logged in, Moogle still thinks of them as being logged in, so the logout option becomes available.

Comment: @LucienStals Well, in that case, Moodle should not "think of them as logged in" unless it is going to take care of also logging them out. This harkens back to early days of the Web when people would write "log on to site suchandsuch.com" (meaning browse to it) and it would drive me nuts. There was no "logging on" occurring, any more than driving to the movie theater was "watching a movie". If we don't clarify proper usage, the terms become meaningless.

Comment: So, this is THE answer, which means I must accept it. It is stupid functionality though. No other web site works this way. Why did they decide to get "creative" about something so fundamental?

Comment: @nocomprende I'm trying to justify Moodles choices, just explain how it works ;) . It took me a while to get my head around it too. This documentation might help... https://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Guest_access